# Unknown tall, cylindrical electronic component

Tags: identification, components

I found the component in the attached photo in a circuit I was tasked to analyse. I have asked several people what this component is, but I haven't gotten an answer yet.

The component is part of an H-bridge circuit board and is connected to both motor output terminals.

Could anyone tell me what this component is and what its purpose could be?

[image: 1]

Comment: Vaguely looks like a polystyrene film capacitor.

Comment: Remove it and measure it using a multimeter.  Probably has no resistance and some value of capacitance; i.e. a film capacitor.

Comment: Easier way should be check where is it connected and then measure the resistance. Possibly also a discharge resistor!

Comment: Since it looks like a stack of disks, and is directly across the motor terminals, I'd guess it's a surge/transient/arc suppressor, See https://patents.google.com/patent/US6847514 for example

Answer (score 1):

@rdtsc and @Unimportant are right it is a film capacitor.

I'm not very sure but it could be [this](https://www.polyplastics-global.com/en/news/2021/09/23/814.html) or maybe not?

[image]

I know this is a very old question to answer but just to remove it from the "Unanswered Questions Section"